# Unable to install Phonegap plugin in Brackets

Tags: cordova, adobe-brackets

I have installed Brackets(Sprint 35). I just wanted to install Phonegap plugin in Brackets through Extension Manager in Brackets. There are two choices for installation. One is direct installation from available plugin and second is install from URL.

- First case showing **Extension error** upon installation.
- Second case showing **Installation failed** .
  I have used the url https://github.com/adobe/brackets-phonegap from github. Please help to install. Please don't tell to downgrade to earlier version of Brackets.[image]

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/adobe/brackets-phonegap/issues/65 -- there's a known incompatibility with Brackets Sprint 35 at the moment.  There are only two workaround options:

- Use Sprint 34 instead
- [Set up a Brackets dev environment to run from](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets#setting-up-your-dev-environment), since the bug only affects minified 'production builds' of Brackets